# How do I create VERTICAL Divs and nav-like bar at the left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are in the end process of finishing our website project for our class, and I am trying to make the view document page of our website, which should look something like the paint image attached.

[View Page prototype image; follow the link because stackoverflow needs reputation to embed images :/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjQOp.png)

I already have a header and footer that I'm going to use from the homepage I made. All I'm trying to do now is to create the inner `div` sections as you can see in the image, and I want them to be like that vertical. I've been searching for samples online, but I can't find what I need.

basically the left div like section is where the documents created will appear as links so that the user would be able to choose from them to view. the website we are making is pretty much a collaboration website where teams of engineers log on to the website, the system will match them to the team name they registered with, and each team will have their own private workspace of the view page doc that im in the process of trying to create now. so each team will have different links at the left side and so its a "dynamic" or "changing" div section. thats why i said its supposed to be like a navigation bar, but isnt one at the same time because it depends on each team's amount of private created documents.

in the middle is where they would be able to view the documents when they click on the link to view from the homepage or from this nav like bar in this view page.

at the right is where we plan to have a team chat . i believe here is where we insert a plugin team chat? unless its an easy thing to start one from scratch :D?

here is the HTML code of whats so far a header, footer, and a middle div section.
CSS follows

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>doc view</title>
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="images/logo.ico">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="css/homepageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <a href=""><img class="logoImage" border="0" alt="logo" src="images/logo.gif"></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="ContentSection1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    padding: 20px 0;
    background: url(../images/HPbg.jpg) no-repeat 100% 0%; 
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    padding: 25px 0;
    background-color: #99CCCC;
    text-align: center;
}

.logoImage { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 47%;
    top: 3.5%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.ContentSection1 {
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: AliceBlue ;
}

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721590/html-css-nav-bars-on-the-left-side-of-page

Comment: @brandelizer  if there was a preview it wouldve helped more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bootstrap grid for this:

HTML:

```
<header>
   ....
</header>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 left"> ... </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 center"> ... </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 right"> ... </div>
</div>
<footer>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green; 
}
.left {
    background-color: yellow;
    height:80px; /* not mandatory */
}
.center {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px; /* not mandatory */
}
.right {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 50px; /* not mandatory */
}
.col-md-12 {
    height: 100px; /* not mandatory */
    padding: 0px;
}
footer {
    background-color: teal;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution... Examples of this in use can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: thank you both. i think this is close to what i want to achieve. ill try play with that

Comment: @goldensunplayer check the updated answer, maybe this helps you better.

Comment: @PavelValeriu it kinda helps, but i wanna do some type of offset on the left and right because the columns are off margin from the full page width. (there is a good chunk of empty space behind the left grid section and after the right grid section.

im hoping to "offset it backwards a little bit from the left side, and frontwards a bit on the right side for them to extend a bit to the width of the page on left and right

im also now getting the footer with empty space under it :/

Comment: Updated css code. Now you don't have any blank space on the left and right side of columns...Footer has white space below it because the content does not take all of the page page width, a quick fix for this is to add `body { background-color: blue /* the color of footer */ }`

Comment: @PavelValeriu how does adding background color increase the page to allow footer go to the bottom?

Comment: nvm i was able to make footer go down by adding to footer in CSS: position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;

Comment: You add a lot of description without explaining the needs. You did not mention that the footer should have a fixed bottom position. Don't forget to accept my answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can simply do this.

```
<div class="col-md-3>
<ul class=" nav nav-pills nav-stacked ">
  <li class="active "><a href="# ">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="# ">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="# ">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="# ">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ">
Center column
</div>
<div class="col-md-3>
    Right column
</div>
```

Comment: This one looks great! however, the footer merges with the divs? also, i want the other two divs to have a label aspect (just like the left div does and then the links follow) same thing, except instead of being a navigation, the center div would load a document, and the right div will have a team chat plugin perhaps. i just want labels though to show what each div is about like the left div shows.

Comment: i kinda fixed it...facing a small issue...regardless thnx again

Comment: i wish i could but i need reputation -.-

Comment: I see. it's okay pal. Happy coding :)